# How to handle PropTypes inside array component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have the following construct:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TitleCell from '../components/TitleCell/TitleCell';

const list = [
    {
        title: 'some title',
        height: '50px',
        render: ({ width }) => (
            <TitleCell
                value={width}
            />
        ),
    },
];

list.propTypes = {
    width: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

I am still getting error "error 'width' is missing in props validation". How can I correct this?

Comment: This snippet doesn't make sense. First, `list` is imported from `'../components/TitleCell/TitleCell'`, so it can't be redefined, and second, what you try to redefine it to is a javascript array, not a React component, so it won't have any propTypes to validate. Are you trying to define the propTypes of `TitleCell`?

Comment: No `list` is not imported from `TitleCell` it is just a representation of the attributes that will be used inside of a material table. So list is basically table heading data. `TitleCell` is just a styling mechanism to help render a table.

Comment: Please explain `import list from '../components/TitleCell/TitleCell';`? Can you clarify what you are trying to define propTypes for?

Comment: @DrewReese sorry, understand you now. It is a typo, corrected it. `TitleCell` is what is being imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be some static code analysis that is interpreting the `render` function as an anonymous functional React component and is thus reporting that propTypes needs to be defined.

Define a local named component and attach defined propTypes.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TitleCell from '../components/TitleCell/TitleCell';

const RenderComponent = ({ width }) => <TitleCell value={width} />;

RenderComponent.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const list = [
  {
    title: 'some title',
    height: '50px',
    render: RenderComponent,
  },
];
```

Comment: Oh no, the error message specifically wants `width` to have prop validation. The error is not related to `TitleCell`

Comment: @Jam1 Can you add the full error message to your question?

Comment: The error is `error 'width' is missing in props validation react/prop-types`

Comment: @Jam1 There is certainly more detail than that. There should some text that says what component is missing the propType and there should be a stacktrace of the component rendering up to that component.

Comment: The component would be `list` it is a `jsx`, that is `list.jsx` file. But `list` happens to be an `array` and not the typical `class` or `function` component. I might just disable prop types `read/prop-types` for files like these. Thanks a lot for the help! Appreciate it.

Comment: @Jam1 I see, `list` isn't a component. Perhaps `render` is being interpreted as an anonymous functional component, I've updated my answer with a possible solution. Outside of this I would need more context as to how `list` is being consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```js
for(const { render } of list) {
  render.propTypes = {
    width: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };
}
```

Comment: This is not working but I like the direction. Will work with this and see if I can come up with a solution thank you.